# Vertx EventBus Reply a 'Specific' Message

Tags: rest, vert.x, event-bus

We have a case as below:

[image]

The concern is that, the Coordinator sends out a message from a method context and gets the reponse from another:

```
private void forwardToVWClient(Message msg) {

        vertx.eventBus().send(RESTClient.ADDRESS, msg.body(), deliveryOptions, res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                log.info("forwardToVWClient. VW got result : success.");
                // do not reply ok until we get an OK from the Listener verticle

            } else {
                log.error("forwardToVWClient VW got result : failure.");
                msg.fail(500, res.cause().getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

then I have another event bus consuming method where I receive the response:

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESS_RESPONSE, this::handleResponseMessage);


private void handleResponseMessage(Message msg) {
        // how to reply the message received in the context of forwardToVWClient ?? 
}
```

So, how could I reply the message in the context of `forwardToVWClient`, when I receive the response in the `handleResponseMessage`?

**Couple of ideas so far:**

1. Put the message in the vertx context ?
2. The message object has a field : `.replyAddress()` that returns an int, I save that in a static ConcurrentHashMap and use it to reply a particular message. I ll post more details as an answer.

Is there a better way?

Comment: i'm probably missing something obvious, but why can't you just invoke `Message.reply()` on the associated `Message` instance passed to the `Handler` of the consumer registered in `CoordinatorVerticle`?

Comment: no worries, my diagram did not help at the end i think :). i ll update the question

Comment: sorry, i'm still a bit confused. tell me if i'm understanding this correctly... there two messages being sent over the bus: first from "RESTServer" to "CoordinatorVerticle", and then from "CoordinatorVerticle" to "VWClient"? and the question is, how to propagate the response from "VWClient" all the way back to "RESTServer"?

Comment: Almost! the catch is : the response does not come from VWClient, it comes from another verticle.

Comment: how does this other Verticle fit into the design? does it host VWClient?

Comment: VWClient makes a rest call to an external service, and receives an ACK only. The actual response comes later through a POST call to another verticle. (VWAPIServer)

Comment: @OrkunOzen Did you find a good way to handle this scenario without maintaining the mapping?

Comment: Nope, even worse yet, in clustering, you cannot rely on the solutions below with ConcurrentHashMap<String, VWApiRequest> pendingCommands. 
we ended up using redis to store the addresses ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to achieve it is to save the `replyAddress` field of the message and use it to send a message back to the originator.

Below is some simplified code that shows how:

```
public class VehicleStateCoordinatorVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {


    final static String ADDRESS_REQUEST = "CoordinatorRequest";
    final static String ADDRESS_RESPONSE = "CoordinatorResponse";

    static ConcurrentHashMap<String, VWApiRequest> pendingCommands = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    public void start() {
        vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESS_REQUEST, this::handleRequestMessage);
        vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESS_RESPONSE, this::handleResponseMessage);
        log.info("===== VehicleStateCoordinatorVerticle - bus consumer ready =====");
    }

    private void handleRequestMessage(Message msg) {

            // .... omitted for brevity
            // save the replyAddress and the command for later/callback
            cmd.setReplyAddress(msg.replyAddress());
            pendingCommands.put(cmd.getVwReference(), cmd);


            forwardToVWClient(msg);
    }


    private void forwardToVWClient(Message msg) {

        vertx.eventBus().send(AbstractOEMClientVerticle.ADDRESS, msg.body(), deliveryOptions, res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                log.info("forwardToVWClient. VW got result : success.");
                // do not reply ok until we get an OK from the VWAPIServer verticle

            } else {
                log.error("forwardToVWClient VW got result : failure.");
                msg.fail(500, res.cause().getMessage());
            }
        });
    }



    private void handleResponseMessage(Message msg) {

        //..
        VWApiRequest vwApiRequest = pendingCommands.get(vwReference);
        if(vwApiRequest == null){
            log.error("No pending vwApiRequest could be found!");
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Instead of targeting the RESTApi address,
         * we use the replyAddress to target the specific message that is pending response.
         */
        vertx.eventBus().send(vwApiRequest.getReplyAddress(), body, deliveryOptions, res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
             // cheers!
            }
            else{
                log.error("Error in handleResponseMessage {}", res.cause().getMessage());
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that ok?
or not. let me know.

```
class AVerticle {

    public void start() throws Exception {
        router.route(path).method(HttpMethod.GET).handler(ctx -> replyHandler(ctx, replyPort));
    }

    private void replyHandler(RoutingContext ctx, String replyPort) {
        
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        
        // send a message and waiting for reply (Msg1)
        Future<Message<Object>> future = vertx.eventBus().request(replyPort
                , Constaints.NO_REPLY
                , new DeliveryOptions()
                    .addHeader(Constaints.NO_REPLY, uuid));

        // then send the real data, markup with the same uuid (Msg2)
        vertx.eventBus().send(replyPort, "your data", new DeliveryOptions()
                    .addHeader(Constaints.UUID, uuid));

        // once received the result, process on.
        future.onSuccess(msg -> {
            HttpServerResponse response = ctx.response();
            String result = msg.body().toString();
            response.end(result);
        });
    }
    
}

class BVerticle {

    // uuid: Msg1_Obj 
    private Map<String, Message<?>> messageMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Message<?>>();

    // you will get two message on replyPort
    public void start() throws Exception {
        msgConsumer = vertx.eventBus().localConsumer(inport, this::msgHandler);
    }

    private void msgHandler(Message<Object> message) {
        // store (Msg1) in memory
        if (Constaints.NO_REPLY.equals(message.body().toString())) {
            messageMap.put(message.headers().get(Constaints.NO_REPLY), message);
        }
        // do what you want with your data (Msg2)
        else {
            // your business code here
            String result = "your result";

            String uuid = json.getString(message.headers().get(Constaints.UUID));

            // get (Msg1) store in memory
            Message<?> theReplyMessage = messageMap.get(uuid);

            // use (Msg1) 's replyAddress to reply (Msg2) 's data
            theReplyMessage.reply(result);

            // clear the memory
            messageMap.remove(uuid);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).