# Vertx how to make Eventbus request to wait for consumer message reply

Tags: java, vert.x

As I am new to Vertx, I was trying request- response using Eventbus, But While trying that I am stuck at once place, what I had done:

```
EventBus bus = vertx.eventBus();
//Here I call the request
bus.<JsonObject>request("previewdata", m ,this::handle);

public  void handle(AsyncResult<Message<JsonObject>> result) {
    //request get fails before consumer don't send reply within 30 seconds
    if(result.succeeded()){
        System.out.println("Answer: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(result.result().body());
    } else{
        result.cause().printStackTrace();
    }
}

IDEng ie = new IDEng();
//Consumer of request
bus.<JsonObject>consumer("previewdata", this::getPreviewData);

public void getPreviewData(Message<JsonObject> message) { 
     JsonObject json = message.body();
     for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
         json.put("flag"+i, "got"+i);
     }
     try {
         //Only for example I had put wait of 40 seconds (so it fail as greate than 30 seconds) it may take more time
         Thread.sleep(40000);
     }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
     }
     message.reply(json);
}
```

I had created one vertx example using Worker Verticle and I have one request and consumer, But request is not waiting for consumer to reply the response and it's get failed in 30 seconds as it's Default timeout is 30 seconds, But per our real time scenario sometime it is not sure that how much time will request take. So please help me how can I wait for response.

I know we can set Timeout using DeliveryOptions but that's not a proper way as we never estimate some tasks time if it depends on third server.
E.g

```
new DeliveryOptions().setSendTimeout(50000)
```

Please let me know if someone can help me out is this or am I doing this in wrong way?

Comment: "how can I wait for response" - I didn't use VertX a lot but wouldn't that violate the basic idea of this being event driven? Thus you wouldn't _wait_ for the response but _react_ on the event of the response being ready.

Comment: @user3458271 may be this can help a bit, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605863/vertx-eventbus-reply-a-specific-message

Comment: @Thomas Yes may be I am wrong but in real time we cannot say which tasks will take how much time because it's depends on many circumstances, so even using event driven how could I acknowledge the requester that yes now consumer has completed the tasks, Here in my case request automatically fails in 30 seconds, and worker Verticle are used for long running processes.

Comment: Well, as you said the problem is that we don't know how long a task might run. Thus you'd want the first response to be just an acknowledgement for the request. Then you'd have basically 2 options: periodically poll for the state of the task or - which would be more the Vert.x way - send a message to the client, e.g. via websocket or push message.

Comment: Poll is not a good idea, and websocket will not fit for application, push message not sure have to see what is exactly is that in vertx.

Comment: If you don't want to just use a large timeout value, then @taygetos' answer is the way to go.

Comment: Yes that I said, I know that option DeliveryOptions setSendTimeout, but that's a bad way of coding, I want some standard way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

how about decoupling the response to a different bus-address e.g "`previewdataresponse`":

Verticle A.)

```
bus.<JsonObject>request("previewdata", m ,this::handle);
// show error if reply is not success

bus.<JsonObject>consumer("previewdataresponse", this::handleResponse);

public void handleResponse(Message<JsonObject> message) { 
    // do something with the reponse
}
```

Verticle B.)

```
bus.<JsonObject>consumer("previewdata", this::getPreviewData);

public void getPreviewData(Message<JsonObject> message) { 
     JsonObject json = message.body();
     //...
     message.reply(json); // acknowledge that you received the message
     try {
         Thread.sleep(40000);
         bus.<JsonObject>send("previewdataresponse", json);
     }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
     }
}
```

Comment: seems to be good idea, but what if I am calling this request through Vertx Routing, and want to send response back using roundingContext.response().end(json).

Comment: @user3458271 This answer doesn't prevent you from doing that, does it? You would just pass the `RoutingContext` into `handleResponse`.

Comment: @dano to pass whole RoutingContext object to handleResponse is not a good way to do it.

Comment: @user3458371 Why not?

Comment: As it is not a good coding practice and yes even I cannot pass RoutingContext as Vertx just work with buffer and JsonObject, and to RoutingContext I have to create MessageCodec this will become messy and lengthy

Comment: You can literally pass any message that you would pass in a reply. Ending the routingContext is also possible after you receive the response-message. Maybe this code snippet is a bit messy, because i used the original code, but i would still recommend this.

Comment: You can also generate a random uuid for consumer address, and setup that consumer one time and handle the routing context there, which is just replicating the reply logic btw